# Location of Azure vhd file on Ubuntu VM?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine

When I try to download a vhd file from Azure storage is that file accessible if I ftp into the server?

It's too slow to download via a browser...runs at about 70k...whereas ftp it's over 2mbs.

Thanks!

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general Azure tech support.

Comment: Also, use `azcopy.exe` to copy to/from storage accounts - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/